# Good method placement in MVC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Simple question.

Is it good practice to place all controller related methods (but not directly used in view) in a helper?

What I mean, my controllers consist of `new`, `create`, `edit`, etc. methods only. Inside these methods there are typically another methods called like:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  include SessionsHelper

  ...

  def destroy
    sign_out if signed_in?
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end

module SessionsHelper
  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def sign_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

Lately I've read that helper should consist of methods used **only** in view, so I am not quite sure whether methods above count as that, and therefore whether my placement of method is a bad practice.

Could somebody point me to relevant documentation that considers this good/bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what controller concerns are for. It is, basically, a regular ruby module, without any added meanings of rails helpers.

```
# app/controllers/concerns/session.rb
module Concerns
  module Session
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def signed_in?
      !current_user.nil?
    end

    def forget(user)
      user.forget
      cookies.delete(:user_id)
      cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    end

    def sign_out
      forget(current_user)
      session.delete(:user_id)
      @current_user = nil
    end
  end
end

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  include Concerns::Session

  helper_method :signed_in? # make it available in views

  def destroy
    sign_out if signed_in?
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: One thing. Take `helper_method :signed_in?` from inside of concern into ApplicationController and place it just after `include Concerns::Session`. Calling `helper_method` inside concern gives `undefined method` error. I have edited your answer, but require peer review.